# Deeplab tensorflow implementation: training custom data. How to choose parameters?

Tags: tensorflow

I try to train the deeplabv3+ with my images and segmentation masks dataset. However, the official github project (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) only provide training VOC, Cityscapes and ADE20K datasets. Therefore, try to follow VOC dataset map to build up my dataset. My aim is to segment desk table from video. I got 80 continue frames from a video. The image shape is **1920*1080**. I used "Labelme" to create the mask of table for this 80 images. The tables in the video frames are similar. I separate them with 60 for training, 20 for validation. The structure is similar to VOC dataset map:

JPEGImages: for RGB colour image,

Segmentation: for txt files containing train filenames, val filenames and trainval filenames,

SegmentationClass: for mask images with colour map.

After that, I modify the "download_and_convert_voc2012.sh" to remove the colour map and create tfrecord files. Then, I modify the "data_gernerator.py" to change the data information of VOC. In the other words I change the original code:

```
_PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 1464, 
        'train_aug': 10582, 
        'trainval': 2913, 
        'val': 1449, 
    },
    num_classes=21,
    ignore_label=255,
)
```

To

```
_PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 60, 
        'train_aug': 432, 
        'trainval': 80, 
        'val': 20,
    },
    num_classes=2,
    ignore_label=255,
)
```

the next step is to use the commond below to do the training:

```
python3 deeplab/train.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --training_number_of_steps=10000 \
    --learning_rate_decay_step=500 \
    --train_split="train" \
    --base_learning_rate=0.0001 \
    --adan_learning_rate=0.0001 \
    --model_variant="xception_65" \
    --atrous_rates=6 \
    --atrous_rates=12 \
    --atrous_rates=18 \
    --output_stride=16 \
    --decoder_output_stride=4 \
    --train_crop_size="513,513" \
    --train_batch_size=1 \
    --dataset="pascal_voc_seg" \
    --tf_initial_checkpoint="/home/.../models/check_point/xception/model.ckpt.index" \
    --train_logdir="/home/.../models/train_log" \
    --dataset_dir="/home/.../models/research/deeplab/datasets/pascal_voc_seg/tfrecord"
```

The initial checkpoint is "xception65_coco_voc_trainval", the dataset of tfrecord files is produced from my 80 images data. However, the training process has loss around 4.8~5.5 up and down in the 10000 steps. I try lower learning rate, but the loss no reducing. I try to change  "--train_crop_size" to "1920,1080", but my computer breakdown. Should I resize my images to around "500*500"? However, I did not reszie my image. After training 10000 steps. Let me show the last 100 steps process:

```
I0201 21:24:03.829240 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9900: loss = 5.0399 (3.194 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9910: loss = 4.8355 (3.152 sec/step)
I0201 21:24:35.473860 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9910: loss = 4.8355 (3.152 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9920: loss = 4.8337 (3.179 sec/step)
I0201 21:25:07.198329 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9920: loss = 4.8337 (3.179 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9930: loss = 4.8411 (3.156 sec/step)
I0201 21:25:38.925366 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9930: loss = 4.8411 (3.156 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9940: loss = 4.8540 (3.188 sec/step)
I0201 21:26:10.489563 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9940: loss = 4.8540 (3.188 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9950: loss = 4.8426 (3.221 sec/step)
I0201 21:26:42.325965 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9950: loss = 4.8426 (3.221 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9960: loss = 4.8415 (3.130 sec/step)
I0201 21:27:14.000005 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9960: loss = 4.8415 (3.130 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9970: loss = 4.9121 (3.163 sec/step)
I0201 21:27:45.751608 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9970: loss = 4.9121 (3.163 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9980: loss = 4.8351 (3.145 sec/step)
I0201 21:28:17.505195 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9980: loss = 4.8351 (3.145 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9990: loss = 4.8401 (3.153 sec/step)
I0201 21:28:49.131623 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 9990: loss = 4.8401 (3.153 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 9990.
I0201 21:28:50.591169 140119415715584 supervisor.py:1050] Recording summary at step 9990.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 10000: loss = 4.8512 (3.149 sec/step)
I0201 21:29:21.474581 140124578015040 learning.py:507] global step 10000: loss = 4.8512 (3.149 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Stopping Training.
I0201 21:29:21.475129 140124578015040 learning.py:777] Stopping Training.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
I0201 21:29:21.475337 140124578015040 learning.py:785] Finished training! Saving model to disk.
/home/.../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py:386: UserWarning: Attempting to use a closed FileWriter. The operation will be a noop unless the FileWriter is explicitly reopened.
  warnings.warn("Attempting to use a closed FileWriter. "
```

After training, I uses the commond below to export the model:

```
python3 deeplab/export_model.py \
  --logtostderr \
  --checkpoint_path="/home/.../models/train_log/model.ckpt-10000" \
  --export_path="/home/.../models/mode_export/table_seg_graph.pb" \
  --model_variant="xception_65" \
  --atrous_rates=6 \
  --atrous_rates=12 \
  --atrous_rates=18 \
  --output_stride=16 \
  --decoder_output_stride=4 \
  --num_classes=2 \
  --crop_size=513 \
  --crop_size=513 \
  --inference_scales=1.0
```

I got the weights model "table_seg_graph.pb". After this, I try to modify the "deeplab_demo.ipynb" to use this model file. I delete the code about the unzip tar file and add code below to load the pb file:

```
class DeepLabModel(object):
  def __init__(self, tarball_path):
    ...
    with tf.gfile.GFile(tarball_path, "rb") as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
       graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    ...
  ...
```

I also change the model download part to model path:

```
download_path = '/home.../models/mode_export/table_seg_graph.pb'
MODEL = DeepLabModel(download_path)
```

then, I load my table image to test the model:

```
def run_visualization(url):
  try:
    original_im = Image.open('/home/.../models/research/deeplab/datasets/pascal_voc_seg/Tabledata/JPEGImages/v00019.jpg')
  except IOErr:
    ...
```

However, the result is nothing. It does not detect anything. **The mask segmenation is all black.**
Because of the video has copy right, I cannot show you the image result.

I just guess I should resize my 1920*1080 to 513*513. Otherwise, I have no idea. Can anyone tell me what sort of parameters I should choose?

what "atrous_rates" I should choose?

What "learning rate" should I give?

What "crop_size" should I give？

Comment: I have same problem, any solution for inference 1920*1080 without resize?